# Netty-Socketio with Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, netty

I am trying to add sockets to my Spring MVC project. I think I should wright something in servlet-context.xml but don`t know what. So I create classes

```
@Component
public class Bootstrap {

    @Autowired
    private SocketIOServer server;

    @PostConstruct
    public void start() {
        server.start();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void stop() {
        server.stop();
    }

}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("controllers")
public class SpringConfig {

    @Bean(name="webSocketServer")
    public SocketIOServer webSocketServer() {

        com.corundumstudio.socketio.Configuration config = new com.corundumstudio.socketio.Configuration();
        config.setHostname("localhost");
        config.setPort(4443);

        final SocketIOServer server = new SocketIOServer(config);
        server.addJsonObjectListener(LogFile.class, new DataListener<LogFile>() {
            @Override
            public void onData(SocketIOClient client, LogFile data, AckRequest ackSender) {
                server.getBroadcastOperations().sendJsonObject(data);
            }
        });

        server.addConnectListener(new ConnectListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnect(SocketIOClient client) {

                  LogFile log = new LogFile();
                  log.setMsg("hello");
                  server.getBroadcastOperations().sendJsonObject(log);

            }
        });

        return server;

    }

}
```

But nothing gonna work. I added client to resources of project and enter link localhost there and have client on my local machine with right link. But still can`t connect. What I am doing wrong? I believe that I mistaken in configuring beans.
Samples I get from this https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio.